# How to create a number field in hibernate limiting count of fractions?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to store numbers in a `postgres` database like `1.5`, `3`, `14.4`. Thus, only numbers with a maximum of one fraction.

Which java-type should I use for these numbers? `float` or `double` or  `bigdecimal`? And how can I restrict the number of fractions to one?

Comment: If you want to save space, you should store the value of the number times 10 (eg: for 1.5, 3 and 14.4 you'll respectively store 15, 30 and 144).

Comment: You should not use `float` or `double`: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: So `@Digits(integer = 2, fraction = 1) BigDecimal` is probably the answer?